# GOTO statement in C#.NET

Tags: c#, goto

```
try
{...
block:
....
}
catch{ ..}
GOTO block
...
....
finally{...}
```

Will goto executes in this case??

Comment: Isn't it a compilation error?

Comment: Maybe it should be called "spaghetti.NET". ;-)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Yes maybe he should have tried to compile it but still.. I don't think they are deserved

Comment: @Pondidum If this worked, it could be used to simulate VB.NET On Error Resume Next.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It won't compile because of '`GOTO block`' instead of '`goto block;`' and even if it was right it won't compile because C# specifications states (§8.9.3):

> The target of a `goto` *identifier* statement is the labeled statement with the given label. If a label with the given name does not exist in the current function member, or if the goto statement is not within the scope of the label, a compile-time error occurs. This rule permits the use of a goto statement to transfer control out of a nested scope, but not *into* a nested scope.

Also I found couple specs interesting for me too:

> A goto statement cannot exit a `finally` block (§8.10). When a goto statement occurs within a `finally` block, the target of the goto statement must be within the same `finally` block, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

And:

> A goto statement is executed as follows:
>
> - If the goto statement exits one or more try blocks with associated finally blocks, >control is initially transferred to the finally block of the innermost try statement. When >and if control reaches the end point of a finally block, control is transferred to the >finally block of the next enclosing try statement. This process is repeated until the >finally blocks of all intervening try statements have been executed.
> - Control is transferred to the target of the goto statement.

the latter means that if you have

```
try
{
    ...
    goto Label1;
}
finally
{
    CloseAll();
}

Label1:
   MethodB();
```

it will call `CloseAll()` before actually transferring control to the `Label1` and executing `MethodB()`.

Makes perfect sense, but I never thought about it...

Comment: the goto is not occuring within the finally block

Comment: @Regent
Actually i had not concentrated on syntax..
I get what i want from your answer
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No. block: label must be outside the try in order for the goto to see it. The code won't even compile. Are you taking a test :)?

Comment: No man, actualy my frnd ask me such question so i was confused so i thought ask question here on Stackoverflow

Comment: I found that reading of C# Language Specification is quite enlightful in such cases :)

Comment: And of course actually trying the code in Visual Studio will give you a lot of information.

Comment: @Regent: enlightening + insightful = enlightful. :D

Comment: Seriously, does anyone read those specs? A lot easier to just test it.

Comment: @erikkallen I suspect the people who give the best responses here have read the specs :-)