# goto vs method in finally block in c#

Tags: c#, goto

I am particularly aware of [C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)  and have analysed why can't i use goto statement in finally blocks but i wonder when i am trying the same thing with using methods the i am finally able to leave the finally block but according to specification i must not. Isn't the `goto moo` and `static void moo()` doing the same act i.e taking me out of finally block?? So why in **first** case it is not working but working smooth in **second** case?

> It is a compile-time error for a break, continue, or goto statement to transfer control out of a finally block. When a break, continue, or goto statement occurs in a finally block, the target of the statement must be within the same finally block, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

It is a compile-time error for a return statement to occur in a finally block.

First Case with Goto statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try{}
                catch (Exception ex){}
                finally
                {
                    goto moo;
                }
            moo:
                Console.Write("Hello");
            }
```

Second case with Methods : it worked!

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try{}
            catch{}
            finally
            {
                moo();
            }
        }
        static void moo()
        {
            int x=2, y=3, a=4, b=7;
            if (x == y)
                return;
            else
                a = b;
        }
```

The GOTO statement is generally considered to be a poor programming practice that leads to unwieldy programs. Its use should be avoided.

Comment: Is there *any* good reason that you want to use `goto` ? The two snippets have nothing in common. The second calls a method. The first tries to break out of the exception finalizer in an uncontrolled manner

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? You will get to the Console.Write without the goto.

Comment: See the [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952306/goto-statement-in-c-net), according to the C# specification "A goto statement cannot exit a finally block (§8.10). When a goto statement occurs within a finally block, the target of the goto statement must be within the same finally block, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs.". [Specification is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx), paragraph about this is near the bottom.

Comment: @Equalsk - I think the OP already knows that - as he has included that extract in the question - he seems to be asking why the specification says that - which really is not a suitable question for SO.

Comment: If you moved the moo: label to just before the closing parenthesis of the finally block wouldn't that give the desired behaviour - assuming you did want to go to the next statement after the finally block. Still best not to use goto though.

Comment: I've clearly got my glasses on upside down today, it's clearly written right there in a big block like you said.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i was trying to see in both case i am trying to migrate from finally statement and in first case i get an error but second case works like charm.

Comment: "as it leads to unnecessary calls"  What?  No it doesn't.

Comment: @Amy The GOTO statement is generally considered to be a poor programming practice that leads to unwieldy programs. Its use should be avoided

Comment: @CommonMan I am quite aware of that, but it doesn't "lead to unnecessary calls".  That's simply wrong.

Comment: @Amy ok, i was very new that time and was learning programming. Thanks for reminder, i edited it now. 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Isn't the goto moo and static void moo() doing the same act i.e taking me out of finally block?

No, absolutely not.

`goto moo` would transfer control out of the `finally` block completely.

`moo()` just calls the method, but then when the method returns you're back in the `finally` block.

If you put a `Console.WriteLine("Still here...")` after your `moo()` method you'll see that.